# Tor don't stop after terminal being closed

Tags: windows, linux, terminal

Tor stays at background after closing the terminal. How can I make it behave like in Windows (Tor only functions while the cmd is still running).
I'm using Tor by just entering `tor` command in terminal -> firefox proxy settings (without tor browser).

I've specified `RunAsDaemon 0` in `torrc` but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Then it should stop once the terminal stops, ensure you're *not* specifing `RunAsDaemon 1` in your torrc or in the command line.

Comment: then it's probably related to however your terminal is closing, it's not taking child processes with it. just use ctrl-c then close the terminal.

Comment: Do you just enter `tor` or something like `tor -f torrc`?

Comment: If you want to stop tor in termux then type "ctrl+c" your tor will stopped

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Linux way to do it:

In a terminal, use "sudo service tor stop." If that doesn't work, try going to System Monitor and ending the process from there. If THAT doesn't work, go to your terminal and type in "sudo killall tor". That should make Tor go away.